# How to get the text of an elemnt and assign as class name in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have about more div like the one below:

```
<div class="adverts-grid-row">
  <div class="adverts-col-100">
    <span class="adverts-widget-grid-link adverts-icon-folder ">
      <a href="http://www.parilinx.burnnotice.co.za/advert-category/classic/">Classic</a>
      (1)
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="adverts-grid-row">
  <div class="adverts-col-100">
    <span class="adverts-widget-grid-link adverts-icon-folder ">
      <a href="http://www.parilinx.burnnotice.co.za/advert-category/classic/">Salsa</a>
      (1)
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Each of the a tag has its own category being displayed.
How can I get the text of a category and add that as a class to the a tag?

I did this:

```
var category = $('span.adverts-widget-grid-link a').text();
    console.log(category);
    $('span.adverts-widget-grid-link a').each(function(){
        $(this).addClass(category);
        console.log(category);
});
```

But it is taking all the categories at the same time and adds as class name.

Comment: Give Id to each <a> and use id selector instead of class

Comment: I cannot to change the html content, that is why am using jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are fetching category name at wrong place. You just need to fetch category name inside the `each` loop.
Try something like this:

```
 $('span.adverts-widget-grid-link a').each(function(){
        $(this).addClass($(this).text());
        console.log(category);
});
```

Instead of this:

```
var category = $('span.adverts-widget-grid-link a').text();
    console.log(category);
    $('span.adverts-widget-grid-link a').each(function(){
        $(this).addClass(category);
        console.log(category);
});
```

```js
$('span.adverts-widget-grid-link a').each(function(){
        $(this).addClass($(this).text());
});
```

```css
.Classic{
 color: red;
}

.Salsa{
 color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="adverts-grid-row">
  <div class="adverts-col-100">
    <span class="adverts-widget-grid-link adverts-icon-folder ">
      <a href="http://www.parilinx.burnnotice.co.za/advert-category/classic/">Classic</a>
      (1)
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="adverts-grid-row">
  <div class="adverts-col-100">
    <span class="adverts-widget-grid-link adverts-icon-folder ">
      <a href="http://www.parilinx.burnnotice.co.za/advert-category/classic/">Salsa</a>
      (1)
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="adverts-grid-row">
  <div class="adverts-col-100">
    <span class="adverts-widget-grid-link adverts-icon-folder ">
      <a href="http://www.parilinx.burnnotice.co.za/advert-category/classic/">Classic</a>
      (1)
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="adverts-grid-row">
  <div class="adverts-col-100">
    <span class="adverts-widget-grid-link adverts-icon-folder ">
      <a href="http://www.parilinx.burnnotice.co.za/advert-category/classic/">Salsa</a>
      (1)
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="adverts-grid-row">
  <div class="adverts-col-100">
    <span class="adverts-widget-grid-link adverts-icon-folder ">
      <a href="http://www.parilinx.burnnotice.co.za/advert-category/classic/">Classic</a>
      (1)
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="adverts-grid-row">
  <div class="adverts-col-100">
    <span class="adverts-widget-grid-link adverts-icon-folder ">
      <a href="http://www.parilinx.burnnotice.co.za/advert-category/classic/">Salsa</a>
      (1)
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check this snippet , this `each` add class for all category , i just add a class for change font and you can see the effect.

Comment: That added a class, but only to the first box. I have more than 4

Comment: @WosleyAlarico , check updated answer. This will add class for all the anchor tag. It is doesn't metter how many blocks you have

Comment: @WosleyAlarico , is this helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

// on hover to each list item to get a tooltip for each list item

```
var category = $('span.adverts-widget-grid-link a').text();
console.log(category);
$('span.adverts-widget-grid-link a').each(function(){
        //var val = $(this).text();
    $(this).addClass($(this).text());
    $(this).attr('title',$(this).text());
    console.log(category);
```

});